# How to use sp_execute passing table parameter

Tags: t-sql, sp-executesql, table-variable

I need to pass a table var to sp_executesql statement. Do you know how can I pass the table variable to sp_executesql?

Here is how I pass the regular variable (not table variable) to sp_executesql

```
EXEC sp_executesql @statement, N'@Status INT',@Status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you don't pass a table variable to execute SQL with sp_executesql.  You make a statement up out of text and execute that.  Like so:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#People') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE tempdb..#People

CREATE TABLE #People (PersonId INT IDENTITY, PersonName VARCHAR(128));

INSERT INTO #People (PersonName) VALUES ('Brett'), ('John'), ('Mark'), ('Shawn'), ('Ryan'), ('Kevin');

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(Max) = 'Select * from #People'

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
```

UPDATE 1-27-17

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#People') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE tempdb..#People
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#People2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE tempdb..#People2

CREATE TABLE #People (PersonId INT IDENTITY, PersonName VARCHAR(128));
CREATE TABLE #People2 (PersonId INT IDENTITY(7,1), PersonName VARCHAR(128));

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO #People (PersonName) VALUES ('Brett'), ('John'), ('Mark'), ('Shawn'), ('Ryan'), ('Kevin');
INSERT INTO #People2 (PersonName) VALUES ('Emily'), ('Beth'), ('Jane'), ('Hannah');

--I. getting an output for a single output variable dynamically
--Say I just want to get Ryan by his Id dynamically and output it
--I need to define one or many parameters OUTSIDE the scope of the Dynamic Sql
DECLARE @Output VARCHAR(8)
DECLARE @PersonId INT = 5

--I then need to associate the parameters as an array, for the purposes of explanation I will use DIFFERENT NAMES you may use the same
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500) = N'@PersonIdInside Int, @OutputInside varchar(8) OUTPUT'

--I then use the names ABOVE in the dynamic sql
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(Max) = N'Select @OutputInside = PersonName from #People Where PersonId = @PersonIdInside'

-- I then do the following AFTER the sp_executesql 1. The Dynamic sql nvarchar, 2. The params nvarchar 3. one or many variables and how they associate
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql, @ParmDefinition, @PersonIdInside = @PersonId, @OutputInside = @Output OUTPUT

-- I have an output so now it should show what I want
SELECT @Output

-- II. getting a result set dymamically to another record set or table OUTSIDE the scope of the internal
-- Create another table, I use a #table for example purposes 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Output') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE tempdb..#Output

CREATE TABLE #Output (PersonId INT IDENTITY, PersonName VARCHAR(8))

--Get a truncated list for an 'in' statement later of person Id's in a variable
DECLARE @People NVarchar(32) = N'1, 5, 10'

--I then use the @People ABOVE in the dynamic sql putting it together and then do an 'insert statement first'
DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR(Max) = N'Insert Into #Output SELECT PersonName FROM (SELECT * FROM #People UNION SELECT * FROM #People2) as x Where PersonId in (' + @People + ')'

--execute yields nothing
EXEC sp_executesql @Sql2

-- or does it?
Select *
From #Output

-- !!! WARNING !!!
-- With dynamic sql you cannot nest multiple dynamic sql statements inside of procs.  EG: Proc1 cannot call Proc2 and both of them have dynamic sql in them.  Engine limitation.
```

Comment: please take a look at the sample I edited the question

Comment: you suggest to use a temp table instead of using var table. correct?

Comment: Ahh okay you want a parameter out from the dynamic sql, I have done that.  Hold up and let me update my example.  I was only using a '#'(table) for the purpose of example.  You may use other objects like permanent tables with structures like nested selects and CTEs too.